# Is there any way to prove that $x = y \Rightarrow x + z = y + z$?

Tags: axioms, natural-numbers

Terence Tao, *Analysis I*, 3e,

> **A.7 Equality**
>
> (...) How equality is defined depends on the class *T* of objects
>   under consideration, and to some extent is just a matter of
>   definition. However, for the purposes of logic we require that
>   equality obeys the following four *axioms of equality*:
>
> - (Reflexive axiom) (...)
> - (Symmetry axiom) (...)
> - (Transitive axiom) (...)
> - (Substitution axiom). Given any two objects $x$ and $y$ of the same type, if $x = y$, then $f(x) = f(y)$ for all functions or operations $f$.

Concerning the *substitution axiom*, I keep wondering if there is really no way one could prove that

$$
x = y \Rightarrow x + z = y + z,
$$

where $x, y, z$ are natural numbers?

Comment: Of course one can prove it, using other axioms of, say, real numbers. But this is not the way here. By the substitution axiom, we obtain this consequence with $f(x)=x+z$ without further ado.

Answer (score 1):

$y+z = (y+0) + z = y+(x-x) + z = (y-x) + x+ z$

if $y = x$ then  $y-x = 0$ and $y+z = x+z$

Comment: Is subtraction defined on natural numbers?

Comment: @MaxHerrmann I was thinking about the field axioms for addition.  The natural numbers are not a field.  I'll have to think for a little bit more on how to do this without the field axioms.